How do I use js-joda timezone operations in node?
I am attempting to use @js-joda/core in this code snippet in a node environment:
LocalDateTime.parse(row.date + "T" + row.time)
    .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))
    .toInstant()
    .toEpochMilli()

I get this error:
ERROR: unsupported ZoneId:America/Los_Angeles 

 {
  "stack": "Error\n    at getRules (/Users/kevin/project/node_modules/@js-joda/core/dist/js-joda.js:4395:15)\n    at ofId (/Users/kevin/project/node_modules/@js-joda/core/dist/js-joda.js:4406:39)\n    at of (/Users/kevin/project/node_modules/@js-joda/core/dist/js-joda.js:10262:27)\n    at <anonymous> (/Users/kevin/project/app/app/scripts/create-tags.ts:119:30)\n    at <anonymous> (/Users/kevin/project/app/app/scripts/create-tags.ts:79:25)\n    at map (native)\n    at <anonymous> (/Users/kevin/project/app/app/scripts/create-tags.ts:79:14)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (native)",
  "message": "unsupported ZoneId:America/Los_Angeles"
} 

I can run this code fine in the browser console at https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/:

What do I need to set up to make this work in a node environment?

Js-joda package has been deprecated, you can use @js-joda/core instead
npm i @js-joda/core @js-joda/timezone

and
you need to import @js-joda/timezone at the top of the file, this will enable time zone
import '@js-joda/timezone';

then try this
LocalDateTime.parse(row.date + "T" + row.time)
    .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))
    .toInstant()
    .toEpochMilli()


Thanks! I am using @js-joda/core. I didn't realize there was an older package with a similar name. All the imports in my project use import rather than require. Can I use that syntax with @js-joda/core too?

yes, also you have to install the additional package @js-joda/timezone
